# Trying to mock Angular2 Token in Test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I'm trying to get a token since its needed in the api authentication to get a list. I start of with importing the angular2-token:

```
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
```

Then I add the describe block:

```
describe('ListComponent Tests', () => {
  let token: Angular2TokenService;

  beforeAll(() => {
    token.init();
    token.signIn('test@email.com', 'foobar');
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

Now I'm uncertain how to actually get a login token in test.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialize the `token` to anything, hence the error. When you create a mock of a service for a component-under-test, often is it enough to just create a [spy](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) for the functions that are expected to be called. Then in the test you just want to check that the component actually calls the functions. You will also need to substitute the real service for the mock service, so you need to configure the mock as provider substitute. For example

```
@Component({
  ...
})
class TestComponent {
  constructor(private token: Angular2TokenService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    token.init();
  }

  onLogin(email, password) {
    token.signIn(email, password);
  }
}

describe('..', () => {
  let tokenStub;
  let component;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    tokenStub = {
      init: jasmine.createSpy('init'),
      signIn: jasmine.createSpy('signIn')
    }

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: Angular2TokenService, useValue: tokenStub }]
    })

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  })

  it('should init the token when component created', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(tokenStub.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

  it('should signin token when component login', () => {
    component.onLogin();
    expect(tokenStub.signIn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test@email.com', 'foobar')
  })
})
```

You can see that you check that the functions are called by using the `toHaveBeenCalledXxx` methods, which can take arguments.

If you aren't using the `TestBed` configuration, then you can easily make it an isolated test by simply doing something like

```
let tokenStub: Angular2TokenService;
let component;

beforeEach(() => {
  tokenStub = {
    init: jasmine.createSpy('init'),
    signIn: jasmine.createSpy('signIn')
  } as Angular2TokenService;

  component = new TestComponent(tokenStub);
})

it('..', () => {
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(tokenStub.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Make sure to read the docs on spies that linked to above. You can do other stuff with spies like make them return specific things, and more.